# STMP client from email js not working on aws amplify

Tags: email, aws-lambda, next.js, aws-amplify, email-client

I am trying to set up an emailing system for users on my website. I am using nextJS and have an api endpoint to send emails. To send the emails I am using emailJS and sending the email to myself with a custom body. Here is the code for my email.js file:

```
 import { SMTPClient } from 'emailjs';  
 
 
export default function handler(req, res) {
 
 const {body, subject}=req.body;
 // console.log(process.env)

  
 const client = new SMTPClient({
   user: "test@gmail.com",
   password: "passward",
   host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
   ssl:true
 });
 
 try{
 
  client.send(
     {
       text: `${body}`,
       from: "test@gmail.com",
       to: "test@gmail.com",
        subject: `${subject}`,
      
     }
     )
   }
 catch (e) {
     res.status(400).end(JSON.stringify({ message: e.message }))
   return;
 } 
  
 res.status(200).end(JSON.stringify({ message:'Mail sending' }))
}
```

The code works when I use it on localhost but it does not work when I deploy to amplify. When I try to make a post request on amplify I get status 200 with the {"message":"Mail sending"}. However, the gmail account never gets the email. I do not get an error message. I do not have 2 step verification on and have allowed less secure apps, but still no emails are being sent. I would really appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `emailjs` library utilizes a queuing system for sending emails. This means that the `send` method adds the email to the queue and sends it at a later time. This can cause issues when using the send method within a lambda function, as the function may close before the email has been sent. To ensure that the email is sent before the lambda function closes, you can use the `sendAsync` method instead. This method returns a promise that will be resolved when the email has been successfully sent.

To send an email using the `sendAsync` method, you can do the following:

```
await client.sendAsync(
     {
       text: `${body}`,
       from: "test@gmail.com",
       to: "test@gmail.com",
       subject: `${subject}`,
     }
)
```